# Consumable Auto Renewing subscriptions iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a question regarding In App Purchases, If I have hundreds of videos in my application that are needed to be purchased like an auto-renewing subscriptions. For example, a user can buy a video for a duration of one month and then it would be renewed automatically.

But I don't want to create a separate in app purchase for all the videos, since the number of videos are liable to change dynamically. So I want a generic auto-renewing subscription for all of these in app purchases, but the problem here is if I make a generic auto-renewing subscription for all these videos and the user buy one of them then the user will have access to all the other videos which he did not buy.

Any ideas how to overcome this problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how I would proceed in this case.

Using in-app purchase for unlocking a single video means you have a productId for that video OR for the unlocking of all the videos. In the latter case, it's something you don't want, as you said (seems reasonable). In the first case, you need to have a different productId for each one of the videos, unless you may not unlock more than one video at the same time. In this case, you could save the videoId somewhere in the cloud or on the device, so that you know which video you can and which video you can't watch.

If the scenario is instead: a user can unlock how many videos he wants, but for each video he has to buy a separate in-app purchase; then I'm not sure in-app purchases as they exist right now is the choice you may want.
Think about the case when a user wants to end an auto-renewing subscription. He will follow these instructions http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4098 and he should find one row for each of the videos he bought. 
This means that on the Apple-side there has to be one productId for each one of the videos, so we're back again at the same point.

The only option I think is to implement your own purchasing system. Maybe if you explain your reasons to Apple during the review process, they won't reject the app. But it's quite risky I have to say.